# Why is the back arrow on Nautilus so small?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, themes

I've noticed that the back arrow next to the folder path is really small. Is there anyway to fix this? It's really annoying.

It looks like this: 
[image: This is what I mean]

[image]

Comment: There you go picture added

Comment: If you have found a better theme, please do mention it for the benefit of others.

Comment: I will but, do you know any good themes? EDIT: I found one http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Evolve-GTK3-Theme-264780816

Comment: I'm using Greybird (`sudo apt-get install shimmer-themes`) but I don't have Nautilus installed and so can't comment on how the back arrow would look with Greybird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer is that you should find a theme that you like instead of the one you've chosen.